# Ext JS: Sorting menu items hangs browser

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a Menu generated by a Component, but the items of this menu aren't sorted alphabetically as the user wants. So, was I was trying to do is to sort the menu items in the `onMenuBeforeShow`, but doing that -surprisingly to me- hangs the browser if we later call the `destroy` method of the component. Here's a simple snippet that shows that behavior:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    // Creating the menu
    var myMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
        width: 100,
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        floating: false,  
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  
        items: [{
            text: 'A'
        },{
            text: 'C'
        },{
            text: 'B'
        }]
    });

    //Sorting the menu items. It doesn't work but it will show the issue
    var menuItems = myMenu.items.items;
    menuItems.sort(function(anItem, anotherItem) {
        var comparisonResult = 0;
        if (anItem.text < anotherItem.text) {
            comparisonResult = -1;
        } else if (anItem.text > anotherItem.text) {
            comparisonResult = 1;
        }
        return comparisonResult;
    });

    //If you uncomment and executed this, browser will die!!
    //myMenu.destroy();    


});
```

Does anyone have some idea pf why this happens, or knows a proper way of sorting the items of a menu? By the way, I'm using Ext JS v4.2

Comment: I suggest to use the beforerender event to sort the items. This avoids to sort them over and over again while the menu shows and hides.

Comment: @LorenzMeyer Sorting the items in `beforerender` handler will not solve the problem. You should not change the `items` collection in any Container after it has been created; use public API instead.

Comment: @AlexTokarev I just read your answer and understand. You got my vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The browser hangs because the JavaScript engine enters an endless loop; and this happens because you've messed up the Menu's internal state. Don't do that.

Instead, sort the items *before* creating the Menu:

```
Ext.define('My.SortedMenu', {
    extend: 'Ext.menu.Menu',

    initComponent: function() {
        var me = this,
            items = me.items;

        me.items = Ext.Array.sort(items, function(a, b) {
            return a.text > b.text ?  1
                 : a.text < b.text ? -1
                 :                    0
                 ;
        });

        me.callParent();
    }
});

Ext.onReady(function() {
    // Creating the menu
    var myMenu = Ext.create('My.SortedMenu', {
        width: 100,
        margin: '0 0 10 0',
        floating: false,  
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),  
        items: [{
            text: 'A'
        },{
            text: 'C'
        },{
            text: 'B'
        }]
    });

    // The menu is destroyed normally
    myMenu.destroy();    
});
```